# Shrinkage factor per variable in logistic regression model using validate in rms package

Tags: validation, logistic-regression

I made a predictive model using logistic regression and backward selection through the lrm function. To internally validate I used bootstrapping through the validate function of the rms package. The output provides the optimism for the following metrics: Dxy, R2, Intercept, Slope, Emax, D, U, Q, B, G and gp. However, I do not understand how I can adjust the regression coefficients for each separate predictor in my model.